# Set the terminal prompt in Ubuntu to show only the working directory name instead of its full path

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have been searching around for a while and have not been able to find an answer to this. Whenever I use the command line in Ubuntu it always lists the full directory back to my home directory, how to I set it to only show the current working directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Best guess for default Ubuntu install

Find where your `PS1` variable is set and change `\w` to `\W`.

You can do an initial check of this method thus:

```
user@computer:~/full/path/to/directory$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
user@computer:~/full/path/to/directory$ export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
user@computer:directory$
```

It is probably being set in your `.bashrc`. If not, check `/etc/bashrc` and override the variable there in your `.bashrc`. You will of course have to do an `exec bash` or source your `.bashrc` for changes made there to take effect.

### Other setups

There are different variations on how to do this depending on what shell you are using and how it is set up. For example, you might conceivably have your prompt set up like this:

```
export PS1='$USER@$(hostname):$PWD$ '
```

In which case you will want to do:

```
export PS1='$USER@$(hostname):$(basename $PWD)$ '
```

Comment: Hey, I just logged back in and found out that the settings did not save.  They worked at first, however they are gone now, any ideas?

Comment: Did you make the changes in your `$HOME/.bashrc`, as I said? If not, you will of course have to make the change every time you open a terminal. Your `.bashrc` is your initialization file.

Comment: Haha, that was silly, I forgot to wq, thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \W\$ '
```

This should work on `debian` based systems.

Alternatively, you can add the following line at the end of `~/.bashrc` file

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1
```

`1` indicates show only the `current directory`. If you set to `2` the `current directory` and its `parent` will be shown.